# How to trigger aria-controls with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a button that opens some accordion. it works well

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionQ" href="#collapse-id" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-id">click to collapse/open</a>
<div id="collapse-id" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-id">some element</div>
```

I would like to trigger the collapse/open from javascript, as if I clicked on the collapse/open button but I can't figure out how to.

I have tried to do `window.location="#collapse-id"` as it is in the link , with no success. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$( "#collapse-id" ).trigger( "click" );
```